# RVM not loading automatically

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have installed RVM and it works.  I can change the version of ruby and do all of the other things expected with RVM.  however, if I close the current terminal window and open a new one, the new terminal window forgets about RVM.  Here's an example:

After opening a new terminal window, I do the following:

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p484 

$ source ~/.bash_profile

$ ruby -v    
ruby 2.1.0p0
```

Ruby 2.1.0p0 is set as the default RVM version.  it only loads properly after I reload bash_profile.

I am using Ubuntu with the kubuntu window manager.  Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

what is the o/p of `$rvm reload and $rvm notes` after you open a new terminal.

Also check out `$rvm list`
This shows the list for ruby installation available with their version and the default currently being used. You can always change this using `$rvm use 1.9.3 --default`. If you want any specific version to be loaded for an application, edit the .rvmrc file specifying the ruby version to be used.